# Rails: Not routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error with my code

[image]

i get this error with this line into my show.html.haml for the comment

```
= link_to comment.user_name, user_path(comment.user_id)
```

in my create action i have this

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user_name = current_user.nickname
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.save!
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "error"
  end
end
```

thank you for your help

Comment: For some reason, `user_id` is nil on your Comment object, you need to fix that. Are you sure all your comments has a non nil user_id?

Comment: https://ibb.co/W57zvp0

I always have a comment with no content that creates without id nothing at the end when I create a new post

for all comment i have user_id into comment tab

Comment: show the code for the view, if you have a comment which you know doesn't have a user_id then there's not sense to have a link_to to that (nonexistent) user for that comment with no user_id

Comment: https://ibb.co/yRcwjxQ
https://ibb.co/P6vtrHr
https://ibb.co/WvwWQCk
https://ibb.co/t3bK38c

you have all controller and show

for user controller i have this 


    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: again, are you sure all the comments for that post have a user_id? maybe you have invalid data on the database, double check that all your comments have a user_id value and the comment creation is setting the value right, the error says that some comment has no user_id, you need to fix that before anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your post view, you build an empty comment for the current post:

```
= render 'comments/form', comment: @post.comments.build
```

That's why, when you iterate on `@post.comments.each`, `@post` has one unsaved built comment without user.

You can fix this by adding a condition like:

```
- @post.comments.each do |comment|
  - unless comment.new_record?
    .div
      %hr
       = link_to comment.user_name, user_path(comment.user_id)
       ...
```

Or you can add in your PostsController:

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

and change `= render 'comments/form', comment: @post.comments.build` to `= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment`
This way `@post.comments` is empty and you can iterate on it without missing id error.

Answer (score 0):

The error being displayed `missing required keys: [:id]` implies that the arguments to `user_path` are not being passed in as we might be expecting them to. `comment.user_id` might be `nil` or you might have to specify explicitly `= link_to comment.user_name, user_path(id: comment.user_id)`